# How to display the license type for each user in office 365 powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to display the username and primary SMTP address of exported users from Office 365 as well as the license type assigned to each user. The output I am getting shows the username is licensed `true` and the SMTP email address but is not showing what license is assigned to that user.

This is the script I have so far:

```
Connect-MsolService
get-msoluser -All | where-object {$_.islicensed -eq "true"} |
Select-Object Displayname,islicensed,
@{n="PrimarySMTP";e={$_.proxyAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -clike "SMTP:*"}}}
```

Gives me an output of:

```
SMPO Admin           True            SMTP:admin@domain.co.za            
Joe Smith            True            SMTP:joe@domain.co.za                
Kevin Smith          True            SMTP:kevin@domain.co.za                     
Monica Smith         True            SMTP:monica@domain.co.za
```

where I would to display

```
Monica Smith         True            SMTP:monica@domain.co.za      EXCHANGE ONLINE PLAN 1  
SMPO Admin           True            SMTP:admin@domain.co.za       ENTERPRISE PACK     
Joe Smith            True            SMTP:joe@domain.co.za         ENTERPRISE PACK      
Kevin Smith          True            SMTP:kevin@domain.co.za       ENTERPRISE PACK
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LicenseAssignmentDetails` property. For example, to generate space-separated list of licenses you can use:

```
| Select-Object Displayname,islicensed,
@{n="PrimarySMTP";e={$_.proxyAddresses | Where {$_ -clike "SMTP:*"}}},
@{n="Licenses";e={$_.LicenseAssignmentDetails.AccountSku.SkuPartNumber -join " "}}
```

The result would be:

```
DisplayName       IsLicensed PrimarySMTP                    Licenses
-----------       ---------- -----------                    --------
FirstName LastName      True SMTP:Name@contoso.com          SPE_E5 MCOPSTNC MCOPSTN_5 FLOW_FREE POWERAPPS_VIRAL POWER_BI_STANDARD
```